# Page.GetRoutUrl in a static method

Tags: url-routing, asp.net-4.0

Some background on what I'm doing

I usually like to have my pages return the url needed to access it. So i will normally have a method like so

```
public partial class ProductDetails : Page
{
    public static string GetUrl(Guid productId)
    {
        return "fully qualified url";
    }
}
```

on my other pages/controls that need to access this page i'll simply set the link as

```
hl.NavigateUrl = ProductDetails.GetUrl(id);
```

I'm toying around with the new UrlRouting stuff in 4.0 and ran into something I'm not sure will work. I'm trying to use the Page.GetRouteUrl in my static method, and obviously it's blowing up due to Page not being static.

Does anyone know if it's possible replicate what i'm doing with GetRouteUrl?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var url = ((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).GetRouteUrl(id);
```

Note:  If you called this method from another page, you may not get the desired result if it's relative-specific in some way...but it's as good as you can get with static I believe.

Comment: marked accepted as it answers my question. thanks!

var url = ((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).GetRouteUrl("product-details", new { productId = productId });

Answer (score 3):

I got GetRouteUrl to work using Nicks suggestion above.

I also found an alternative way to do it w/o using the GetRouteUrl. You are basically generating it manually using GetVirtualPath

```
public static string GetUrl(int productId)
{
    var parameters = new RouteValueDictionary { { "productId", productId } };
    var vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "product-details", parameters);
    return vpd.VirtualPath;
}
```

Comment: I needed a hack to get a routed URL inside an ashx IHttpHandler and this worked great. I definitely couldn't cast my handler as a Page, so thank you.